# How to replace a value with "." in sed

Tags: sed

I want to replace all instances of "a number followed by any number of spaces followed by a period and possibly more spaces" with the number and period only.

For example, `'14   .   x'` will become `'14.x'`.

My test data is:

```
1. c4 e5 2. g3 c6 { good move. } 3. Bg2 Nf6 4. Nc3 $6 d5 5. cxd5 cxd5 6. Qb3 Nc6 $1.. Nxd5  Nd4
8. Nxf6+ Qxf6 9. Qd1.f5 10. d3 Rc8 (10... Bb4+ $5 11. Bd2 Bxd2+  12. Qxd2 Qa6 $1.3. Rc1.xa2
14. Bxb7 $2 Rb8 15. Qb4 Bd7) 11. Kf1.c5  12. Nf3 O-O
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get an answer, but your example data is confusing.  It is not clear whether that is input our output (probably output), nor is it clear what happened to the numbers for moves 7 or 13.  In future, please provide the input and the desired output.  It would be helpful if you edited this to provide the missing data (input or output) and labelled the input as input and the output as output.  Note that to indent material as code, select it then press the **`{}`** button above the edit box.  It's also a good idea to show what you've tried, in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want *any* number of spaces removed from *either* side of the period, you should try `s/\([0-9]\) *\. */\1./g`:

```
$ echo '11.  A 12  .B 13  .  C 14.D 15 . E' | sed  's/\([0-9]\) *\. */\1./g'
11.A 12.B 13.C 14.D 15.E
```

For your test data, the results are:

```
1.c4 e5 2.g3 c6 { good move. } 3.Bg2 Nf6 4.Nc3 $6 d5 5.cxd5 cxd5 6.Qb3 Nc6 $1.. Nxd5  Nd4
8.Nxf6+ Qxf6 9.Qd1.f5 10.d3 Rc8 (10... Bb4+ $5 11.Bd2 Bxd2+  12.Qxd2 Qa6 $1.3.Rc1.xa2
14.Bxb7 $2 Rb8 15.Qb4 Bd7) 11.Kf1.c5  12.Nf3 O-O
```

Comment: @verlager, "doesn't work" is *NOT* a very good bug report :-) It may be worth stating what it *does* do. You may also want to try the transcript I provided, which *did* actually work.

Comment: echo  1. c4 e5 2. g3 c6 3. Bg2 Nf6 4. Nc3 $6 d5 5. cxd5 | sed 's/\([0-9]\) \./\1./g'

Comment: 1. c4 e5 2. g3 c6 3. Bg2 Nf6 4. Nc3 d5 5. cxd5 = dw

Comment: @verlager, I see no backslashes on the parentheses in what you posted. I assume that was just a typo since it would error otherwise. In addition, your test data is digit-period-space, *not* digit-space-period as your question stated. *That's* the real problem you have here. I've updated the answer to cover both cases.

Comment: Your sample solution does indeed work. But when I substitute my string for your string the space before the period remains: echo 1. c4 e5 2. g3 c6 3. Bg2 Nf6 4. Nc3 $6 d5 5. cxd5 |  sed 's/\([0-9]\) \./\1./g' ====> 1. c4 e5 2. g3 c6 3. Bg2 Nf6 4. Nc3 d5 5. cxd5

Comment: @verlager, your most recent test data does not *have* any spaces before periods. It has spaces *after* periods but you haven't yet made it clear what you really want. You need to better formulate the question, primarily do you want to remove spaces *before* the period, *after* it, or on *both* sides?

Comment: I want to delete the spaces(s) BOTH before and after the period.

Comment: I think I got it ! Thank you so much!